# Post using wp.newPost (WordPress XML-RPC API)

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to add a post into `WordPress 4.3.1` using their XML-RPC API - it works fine, except that it's adding only 1 category, and also, I don't know how to upload and set a featured image.

**wordpress.class.php:**

```
<?php
WordPress();

function WordPress() {
    $params = xmlrpc_encode_request(
        'wp.newPost',
        array(
            0,
            'username',
            'password',
            array(
                'post_title' => 'Test subject',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'terms_names' => array(
                    'post_tag' => array(
                        'Tag 1',
                        'Tag 2',
                        'Tag 3'
                    ),
                    'category' => array(
                        'Category 1',
                        'Category 2',
                        'Category 3'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://domain.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```